# PC won't work unless rebooted

Tags: performance, freeze, repair

When I turn on my PC, it starts alright but within a few minutes it starts to work too slowly, not allowing me to do anything, not even opening an Internet browser. Sometimes it even freezes. If I reboot it, then it works fine. So I have to turn on my PC twice each time I want to use it in order to make it work properly. This is pretty uncomfortable and it is indeed an unexpected behaviour. I don't know what the problem could be and how to solve it.

I ignore what information you need to help me out with this, but below I give you some of the specifications of my PC:

OS: Windows 7 Ultimate Service Pack 1

Processor: AMD A10-5800K APU 3.80 GHz

RAM: 8GB DDR3

GPU: AMD Radeon R7 200 Series

Comment: Did you try booting into safe mode and see if the problem occurs? And did you also try disabling all startup programs. Maybe it is caused by a program or virus.

Comment: Create a new login user with admin privileges. Does the computer still act the same with this login?

Comment: @mpboom I have disabled some of startup programs and nothing has changed. Should I try disabling them all? I'm trying the safe mode thing tomorrow, I'm not at home right now. I'll let you know what the results were

Comment: @JohnnyVegas My user account already has admin privileges, so that's not the problem

Comment: @M.S. Yeah, I should try disabeling all startup programs. You can do this easy by pressing Windows key + R, opening "msconfig", navigating to the general tab and untick the start programs tab. And I think that what JohnnyVegas said was not about the privileges, but about creating another account (maybe the problem is in that area).

Comment: I asked you to create an admin account, login to it, and see if the problem is still there.

Comment: @JohnnyVegas Sorry, I misunderstood you. I'm trying that tomorrow and will post here what happened, thank you both

Comment: Disabling every startup program (except those of Microsoft) worked. Thank you both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have a good system it's not due to the performance of the system. So...

First check out whether the hard disk has been properly connected. Loose contacts may result in such problems.

Secondly, check whether or not you have installed and updated your drivers. In some cases performance lag is shown due to missing proper drivers.

Thirdly, try reducing startup programs which will use more memory and processor, which result in lagging.

If the problem still occurs try scanning your system, maybe it's due to a virus.